# How to secure azure pre-production web app

Tags: azure-web-app-service

we want to use azure web apps not only for production but also for pre-production sites. These sites should be accessible only for Users in our Azure AD or even better only users with specific roles in the Azure AD. Or as a workaround some form of authentification without changing the code of the App. Since the App should be available public in some point of time.

At the moment these web servers are hosted in our internal network so they are only accessible through vpn or on site.

How can I secure a pre-production web app? 
I tried the built in  authentifcation with AD but I can't authorize a specific AD Role or AD Directory without changing the application it self.

What would be perfect for us would be a simple Basic Auth on the web app which I understand is also not possible without changing the App.

Anyone facing the same problem?

Maybe there is a design pattern for this? Or some Gateway to handle this?
Any hints would help,

Thanks
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Follow this article which shows how to configure Azure App Service  to use Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) as an authentication provider.

Some best practices when setting up your app and authentication:

- Give **each** App Service app its own permissions and consent.
- Configure **each App Service app with its own registration.**
- Avoid permission sharing between environments by using separate app
  registrations for    separate deployment slots. When testing new
  code, this practice can    help prevent issues from affecting the
  production app.

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad**

Comment: Thank you, but this does not suite our needs. If I use this documentation I can log in from any Azure AD. How can configure it only to use our Azure AD?